# update trigger with a condition

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2014-express

I have an update trigger which runs if field 'urejeno' gets modified.

```
USE [MYDATABASE]
GO

create trigger trg_MyTrigger on dbo.mytable 
after update 
as 
    if @@ROWCOUNT = 0
        return

    set nocount on

    if UPDATE (UREJENO)
       update mytable 
       set UREJENO_KDAJ = getdate(),
           UREDIL_KDO   = USER_NAME()
       from mytable S
       inner join Inserted I on S.TW_ID = I.TW_ID
```

However I would like to add a condition so that if 'urejeno' = True
the trigger does what is described above but if the condition is 'False'
I want to set the mentioned fields to NULL.

What must I change ?

Comment: Add the update to null into else part of the if statement?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could add another update query in an else part of the conditional, or you could rewrite your update and use the bit value as the conditional directly.

This should work (if I understood you intent correctly).

```
CREATE TRIGGER trg_MyTrigger ON dbo.mytable 
AFTER UPDATE 
AS 
    IF @@ROWCOUNT = 0
        RETURN
    SET NOCOUNT ON

    IF UPDATE(UREJENO) 
    BEGIN
    UPDATE mytable 
    SET 
       UREJENO_KDAJ = CASE WHEN I.UREJENO = 1 THEN GETDATE() ELSE NULL END,
       UREDIL_KDO   = CASE WHEN I.UREJENO = 1 THEN USER_NAME() ELSE NULL END
    FROM mytable S
    INNER JOIN Inserted I on S.TW_ID = I.TW_ID 
    END
GO
```

This would set the two fields to null if UREJENO was updated to 0 (false), but UREJENO was set to 1 (true) then getdate() and user_name() would be used.

Comment: I think you are missing something here ...Should it not go CASE WHEN UPDATE(UREJENO) =True ? I tried your suggestion and the fields get updated no matter true or false.

Comment: 'UREJENO' is a boolean field (bit)

Comment: @user763539 Oh, so you want to run the update if the field is true? I misunderstood then, will change the answer in a minute.

Comment: @user763539 If changed it so that if checks if the update was done on the urejeno column and if it was and new value is true (1) then updates using the functions, otherwise with null.